# Comparing two JSON objects irrespective of the sequence of elements in them

Tags: python, json

Is there any way / class / module in python to compare two json objects and print the changes/differences?

I have tried with "json_tools" which is gives fairly good results, however diff failed in case if there are python lists' with elements in different orders in two json objects.

e.g.

### JSON 1:

```
{
    'Person' : 
        {
            'FName'    : 'John',
            'LName'    : 'Rambo',
            'Sex'      : 'Male'
            'Height'   : '6 ft',
            'Weight'   : '90 KG',
            'Children' :
                [
                    {
                        'FName'  : 'Anna',
                        'LName'  : 'Rambo',
                        'Sex'    : 'Female',
                        'Height' : '5 ft',
                        'Weight' : '55 KG',
                    },
                    {
                        'FName'  : 'Jemmy',
                        'LName'  : 'Rambo',
                        'Sex'    : 'Male',
                        'Height' : '5 ft',
                        'Weight' : '60 KG',
                    }

                ]
        }
}
```

### JSON 2:

```
{
    'Person' : 
        {
            'FName'    : 'John',
            'LName'    : 'Rambo',
            'Sex'      : 'Male'
            'Height'   : '6 ft',
            'Weight'   : '90 KG',
            'Children' :
                [
                    {
                        'FName'  : 'Jemmy',
                        'LName'  : 'Rambo',
                        'Sex'    : 'Male',
                        'Height' : '5 ft',
                        'Weight' : '60 KG',
                    },
                    {
                        'FName'  : 'Anna',
                        'LName'  : 'Rambo',
                        'Sex'    : 'Female',
                        'Height' : '5 ft',
                        'Weight' : '55 KG',
                    }
                ]
        }
}
```

json diff shows the Two jsons are mismatched.. Logically those are identical..

Is there a good way of json matching and comparing in python?

Answer (score 27):

You can use [jsondiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsondiff/)

```
from jsondiff import diff
diff(json1, json2)
```

... assuming you have json1 and json2 loaded with the json entries from your example (and by the way, you have a missing comma after the 'sex' entry).

Comment: Great answer! Helped me compare two auto-generated json files and work the differences until the `diff` output was empty, just like I wanted.

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851183/how-to-compare-two-json-objects-with-the-same-elements-in-a-different-order-equa/25851972 this link more helpful

Comment: does this work on nested array of json objects as well?

Answer (score 17):

you can use [deepdiff](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff#ignore-order) with `ignore_order=True`

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, 3]}}
t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 3, 2, 3]}}
ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2, ignore_order=True)
print (ddiff)
{}
```

Comment: There's a difference in  between _[1, 2, 3]_ from **t1** and _[1, 3, 2, 3]_ from **t2**. How come the output is empty??

Comment: @AfsanAbdulaliGujarati you can add `report_repetition=True` if you want to be alerted for repetitions. see their docs

Comment: deepdiff looks neat, thanks

Answer (score 9):

> Logically those are identical.

They're not. Order matters in a JSON array. I don't know of any tools that will ignore order for you. You could try recursing over the deserialized structure, turning lists into some sort of multiset and dicts into some sort of hashable, frozen dict (so you can put them into multisets), then running your own diff routine on that.

Comment: how we can use this by ignoring some keys?

Answer (score 3):

You could try doing a diff on the results of `json.dumps(jobj, sort_keys=True)`

Comment: `sort_keys` won't reorder JSON arrays; it only affects the order in which JSON object key-value pairs are serialized.